# Function not defined on Google Dataflow

Tags: python, pipeline, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

when i run the following code, that it takes CSV files from a GCS bucket and, after validating them it publishes messages to PubSub, using the DirectRunner with Python it works fine:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
import json


def read_csv_file(pipeline, file_path):
  """Reads a CSV file and returns a PCollection of rows.

  Args:
    pipeline: A Beam pipeline.
    file_path: The path to the CSV file.

  Returns:
    A PCollection of rows.
  """

  rows = (
    pipeline
    | "Read CSV" >> beam.io.ReadFromText(file_path, skip_header_lines=1)
    | "Split CSV lines" >> beam.FlatMap(lambda content: content.split("\n"))
    | "Parse CSV" >> beam.Map(lambda line: line.split(","))
    | "Create record dictionaries" >> beam.Map(lambda record: {
        'id': int(record[0]),
        'firstname': record[1],
        'lastname': record[2]
     })
    )
  

  return rows


def write_to_pubsub(rows, publisher):
  """Writes a PCollection of rows to Pub/Sub.

  Args:
    pipeline: A Beam pipeline.
    rows: A PCollection of rows.
    topic_name: The name of the Pub/Sub topic.

  Returns:
    A PCollection of elements.
  """
  data_str = json.dumps(rows)
  print(f"Preparing a JSON-encoded message:\n{data_str}")
  data = data_str.encode("utf-8")
  # Publish records to Pub/Sub
  publisher.publish("projects/XXX/topics/topic1", data=data)


def print_rows(rows):
  rows | beam.Map(lambda row: print(row))
  

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Job options
  options = PipelineOptions(
    project='XXX',
    runner='DataflowRunner',
    streaming=True,
    job_name='dataflow-job',
    staging_location='gs://dataflow-bucket/staging',
    temp_location='gs://dataflow-bucket/temp',
    region='europe-west8',
    requirements_file='./requirements.txt'
  )

  publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()

  # Create a pipeline.
  pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

  # Read the CSV file and publish to pubsub
  rows = read_csv_file(pipeline, "gs://dataflow-bucket/input/*.csv") | beam.ParDo(lambda rows: write_to_pubsub(rows, publisher))

  # Run the pipeline.
  pipeline.run()
```

Otherwise if i use DataFlowRunner on Google with the same code, I receive the following error:

```
"Error message from worker: generic::unknown: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1418, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 625, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "/Users/amedeo.tortora/Work/personal_execises/beam/gcp/pipeline3.py", line 75, in <lambda>
NameError: name 'write_to_pubsub' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 295, in _execute
    response = task()
```

Can you help me please to solve the issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Is everything defined within the same python file?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code. I would recommend reading the programming guide regarding [ParDo](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo)s and [PTransform](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#composite-transforms)s (and [here](https://beam.apache.org/contribute/ptransform-style-guide/)) - there it is explained better than I can do in this answer.

The general rule of thumb: If you want to outsource a pipeline snipped (code containing the pipe symbol `|`) you use a `PTransform`. In a `ParDo` you may define custom code. However, this is done in the method `process` and not via a lambda function.

For your example, I would recommend changing the following. Your `read_csv_file` should be made a proper `PTransform`, like

```
class ReadCsvFile(beam.PTransform):
  """Reads a CSV file and returns a PCollection of rows.

  Args:
    file_path: The path to the CSV file.

  Returns:
    A PCollection of rows.
  """
  def __init__(self, file_path):
      self.file_path = file_path

  def expand(self, pcoll):
  rows = (
    pcoll
    | "Read CSV" >> beam.io.ReadFromText(file_path, skip_header_lines=1)
    | "Split CSV lines" >> beam.FlatMap(lambda content: content.split("\n"))
    | "Parse CSV" >> beam.Map(lambda line: line.split(","))
    | "Create record dictionaries" >> beam.Map(lambda record: {
        'id': int(record[0]),
        'firstname': record[1],
        'lastname': record[2]
     })
    )

  return rows
```

Furthermore, while technically possible to use the Python PubSub library, I would recommend using the [built-in beam output](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.WriteToPubSub) (it is optimized with respect to parallelism etc.).

The pipeline would then look like this

```
  # Create a pipeline.
  pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

  # Read the CSV file and publish to pubsub
  (
      pipeline
      | "Input" >> ReadCsvFile(file_path="gs://dataflow-bucket/input/*.csv")
      # Not sure, but could be that you need to encode your dict
      # | "ConvertForOutput" >> beam.Map(lambda row: json.dumps(row).encode('utf-8')) 
      | beam.io.gcp.pubsub.WriteToPubSub(topic=my_topic)
  )

  pipeline.run()
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for you solution. Yes i was doing something wrong with ParDo. Now it works fine. 
I only cannot understand if the ReadFromText method loads the entire file in memory or not because csv that i need to elaborate are huge and don't want to risk to have an out of memory.

Comment: I have never worked with `ReadFromText`. I would recommend reading the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.textio.html#apache_beam.io.textio.ReadFromText), or searching on how to read in chunks.